# Image not showing at first click of modal

Tags: javascript, php, html

At first click the modal will show and the image is not showing but after second or third click the image will now popup in modal.

here's the code:

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
   var imageName = "sample.jpg";
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = "<?php echo Configure::read('app.dir'); ?>uploads/field_execution/images/"+imageName;
   if(image.width != 0){
      console.log("Not Error");
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more of your code.

Comment: Reason may be height of modal is 0px when the image is trying to load or display. Check for the height of image & modal container Still need more code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is some lack of context, but the most probable issue is that on the first click your image isn't loaded yet, because you are creating it at that moment (as I suppose) and on following clicks image taken from cache and shown.